# How to bind Ruby on Rails standard webserver ( 127.0.0.1:3000 ) to a more meaningful address on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, hosts

I need to configure ruby standard webserver to listen to

```
localhost.ruby
```

instead of the standard

```
127.0.0.1:3000
```

i tried modifiying the hosts file like this

```
127.0.0.1                localhost.here ( this is apache for PHP )
127.0.0.1/webwidget       webwidget ( still apapche for another project )
127.0.0.1:3000            localhost.ruby
```

flushing the dns

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and then restarting the browser but no effect. I'm on windows 7

Comment: You can't specify ports in host file, so you will always need to add this `:3000` to the address, unless you run it with `rails s -p 80` (may require rvmsudo).

Comment: @BroiSatse sorry i forgot to specify i'm on Windows

Comment: Does not make much of the difference - you can't specify ports on Windows neither. You can still run it on port 80 though (assumiing nothing alse is using it - you should be able to check it with `netstat -a`)

Comment: @BroiSatse add it as an answer i will accept it